# Get number of lines in file and add first 40 characters

Tags: c#

As part of an assignment -

1. The User selects a file extension (.txt, .bat, or .xyz)
2. A list of files from a folder with that extension is shown
3. The user then selects a file from the list and are shown the first 40 characters of each of its first four lines (or as many lines as present if less than four lines are recorded in the file). If there are more lines left in the file, output a string: “xx more lines are not shown.” (substitute xx with the correct number).

I can't seem to wrap my head around number 3. Any help or pointers are greatly appreciated.

```
namespace unit9Assignment
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //add the extensions to the c box. 
            comboBox1.Items.Add(".txt");
            comboBox1.Items.Add(".xyz");
            comboBox1.Items.Add(".bat");

            //make .txt the default selection
            comboBox1.SelectedItem = ".txt";
            tabControl1.SelectedIndexChanged += tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }

        /******Tab Click Event********/
        private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            switch ((sender as TabControl).SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0:
                    break; 
                case 1:
                    fileName(comboBox1.Text);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    fileContent(Files.SelectedItem.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }
        /******Get Files Based on Selection*******/

        public void fileName(string fileExt)
        {
            List<string> listOfFiles = new List<string>(); 
            string[] fileExtArray = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Public", "*" + fileExt);
            foreach (string fileExtFile in fileExtArray)
            {
                listOfFiles.Add(fileExtFile);
            }
            Files.DataSource = listOfFiles;
        }

        /******Display 4 Lines @ 40 Characters Per Line*********/

        public void fileContent(string fileName)
        {
            int numberOfLines = File.ReadLines(@fileName).Count(),
            remainingLines = numberOfLines - 4;
            //THIS PRINTS OUT 4 LINES @ 40 CHARACTERS PER LINE IF A FILE HAS LESS THAN 5 LINES 
            if (numberOfLines < 5)
            {
                foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(fileName))
                {
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(line.Substring(0, 40) + Environment.NewLine);
                    Console.WriteLine(line.Substring(0, 40));
                }
            }

            // NO CLUE WHAT TO DO
            else
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I didnt (and wouldnt) vote this down, but some of these problems are very common and a simple google search would have the answers.  Hope my answer helps you along!

Comment: Didn't downvote either but I would based on the fact that you've included way too much irrelevant information for this problem.  We don't need to know about the assignment or the fact this is in a form.

Comment: @paqogomez I tried Googling for the past hour or so. I guess I didn't know what to Google.

Comment: @Austin Salonen I will keep that in mind for next time. Thanks guys. I really appreciate it!

Comment: @this_guy Dont forget those upvotes!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking the number of lines in the file, why don't you just go ahead and start printing, and stop after 4 lines? Something like this:

```
StreamReader fileIn = new StreamReader(fileName);
for(int i=0; i<4 && !fileIn.EndOfStream; ++i)
{
    string line = fileIn.ReadLine();
    if(line.Length > 40)
        richTextBox1.AppendText(line.Substring(0,40) + Environment.NewLine);
    else
        richTextBox1.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
}
int j;
for(j=0; !fileIn.EndOfStream; ++j)
    fileIn.ReadLine();
if(j>0)
    richTextBox1.AppendText(j.ToString() + " more lines are not shown.";
fileIn.Close();
```

... To clarify, this would be your entire fileContent method. You actually do not need to know the number of lines in the file. Of course, this method won't work if you have more lines in your file than an int variable can hold, but I assume you're not working with such long files.

Comment: Thanks for the help Kevin T. I guess in the future, I should take a step back and think about the logic.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be advisable. Computer logic is different from human logic - it's sequential, rather than "collective," for lack of a better term. In other words, you go through one step at a time (divide and conquer, perhaps?) rather than looking at the big picture and biting the chunks you want. The strength of this is that the sequential logic should work for every possible case, while the "collective" method changes for each case. So, you kind of have to start thinking like a computer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
public void fileContent(string fileName)
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines(@fileName);
    foreach (string line in lines.Take(4))
    {
        richTextBox1.AppendText(line.Substring(0, 40) + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    var remaining = lines.Count() - 4;
    if (remaining > 0)
        richTextBox1.AppendText(remaining + " more line(s) are not shown.");
}
```

The Take() documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Agreed, but nothing says "I'm learning C# " like a linq query.

Comment: This will fail when a line has fewer than 40 characters.

Comment: I tried this, but I am getting an 'ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled' error

Answer (score 1):

Giving answers to homework is bad practice.  Instead here are some pointers to help you wrap your head around your problem:

```
//read a file
var lines = File.ReadLines("myfile");
//get the first 4 lines of your file
var first4 = lines.Take(4);
//get the first 40 characters of the first line of your file
var first40Chars = lines.FirstOrDefault().Take(40);
//get the remaining number of lines
var remainingCount = lines.Count() - 4;
```

Pulling up a dialog to show files is quite easy also.  The [WinForms FileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can help you there.